# Foreign Key Problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

1. `DeptMast`
2. `EmpMast`

Both of tables have a column called `DeptName` and I have primary keys on `DeptName` in both tables.

Now when I go to create a foreign key on column `DeptName` of `EmpMast`, SQL Server gives me this error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'DEPTMAST' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_Key'.

If I create unique index on `deptmast.Deptname` then I don't get any error. Why does this happen?

Comment: You might think about going back and accepting some answers to previous questions. It will make the community much more responsive.

Comment: Can you **show us** the T-SQL statement you use to create the foreign key relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You marked it as a primary key, so it cannot be a foreign key as well. A foreign key can appear multiple times in the table, while a primary key cannot.

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].Empmast  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Fk_DBName_DBColumn] FOREIGN KEY(DEPTNAME)
REFERENCES [dbo].DEPTMAST (DEPTNAME)

Comment: You said you created two tables which each have a primary key of `DeptName`. The primary key cannot be a foreign key as well.